# How do I style the hover colour of the text in the sub menu?

Tags: css, wordpress

I have this website I'm working on. Bear in mind I'm not a professional.

Id like to CSS style the font colour, whilst hovering, in the submenus.

Any clues how to do this?

Cheers,
Matt

https://willcruickshank.net/new/

Answer (score 1):

Currently, this is the CSS that controls the hover color of the font in the sub-menu:

```
.mn-sub li a.active{
   background: rgba(255,255,255, .09);
   color: #f5f5f5 !important;
}
```

You can change the color on hover to something else by just swapping out the #f5f5f5 with any other color hex code. To make it blue (#0000FF), for example:

```
.mn-sub li a.active{
   background: rgba(255,255,255, .09);
   color: #0000FF !important;
}
```

Goodluck!

Comment: thanks stephen. when i add

.mn-sub li a.active{
   background: rgba(255,255,255, .09);
   color: #0000FF !important;
}

to my custom css.... it doesnt change the hover state. the type still seems to dissapear on hover. and it doesnt turn blue

Comment: You would need to change the CSS, not add more. Because the current CSS uses !important, you cannot override it. If your Wordpress theme doesn't allow you to do that, then the best way would probably be to just change the hover color with your Wordpress theme or plugin editor rather than adding custom CSS.

Comment: ah ok. so important is a function. thought it was just an author comment. so if i deleted important from the css file.... i could maybe override it? thanks btw appreciate the reply!

Comment: !important isn't so much a function; it's more of a command that says makes sure that this line of code it overrides everything else. If you delete !important from the original file then you could override it with !important in your custom CSS. But if you are able to delete !important you should be able to just change the color in the original CSS too.

Answer (score 0):

In your css file, with the class name given to your submenu items, you can define parameters for on hover:

```
.mn-sub li a:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: is there a way to find the class given to the sub menu. the inspecter is a bit confusing for me...

Comment: excuse my ignorance... how do i do that?

Comment: ok i have done this. 1 deleted the important 2 added your code... still no joy. just realised is the type becoming transparent as hovered over?